# tcl script that executes fine in linux is not getting executed in windows

Tags: linux, windows, tcl

tcl script

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh
set cmd { perl tt.pl }
lappend cmd {>&@stdout}
catch { exec -ignorestderr  {*}$cmd }
```

calling perl script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Stdout redir\n";
exit 1;
1;
```

So the output in linux would be

```
"Stdout redir"
```

However when i execute same tcl on windows .nothing happens or no output ? Why ?

Comment: Is `perl` in the windows `PATH`? Type `echo %PATH%` is an command line to be sure.

Comment: Does the Tcl `autoexec_ok` command find `perl` for you?

Comment: How are you executing the script on windows?